# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined when importing function - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript. I've imported the `output` function from `console.ts`:

```
export function output(value: any): void {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Which compiles to `console.js`:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var console_1 = require("./console");
console_1.output('Hello');
//# sourceMappingURL=functional.js.map
```

Importing and usage in destination file:

```
import {output} from "./console";
output('Hello');
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I got no compiling error, but not understanding why I got the following error in the browser:

[image]

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at functional.js:2
```

Comment: how are you bundling your files? export, import only work in nodejs, to run in browser you need a module bundler like `webpack`

Comment: I'm Using IntelliJ with TypeScript built-in and some plugins..nothing special everything is simple.

Comment: bowser doesn't have imports or exports. If you want to test your code, run it in node.js.

Comment: @nrgwsth even when test in node: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue in a Vue.js / TypeScript project. Vue.js project used Webpack under the hood and I've run `npm link` during an external module development.

Eventually, I've discovered the issue was caused by Webpack trying to follow the symbolic link to the dependency I've linked with `npm link` command.

The solution was to instruct Webpack to stop following symbolic links.

Relevant Webpack documentation section: [resolve.symlinks](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvesymlinks).

Relevant Vue.js troubleshooting section: [Vue.js and npm link](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/troubleshooting.html#symbolic-links-in-node-modules).

Comment: Thanks, I think this could be very important to notice if Webpack used. I wasn't using any bundling tools, or any dependencies, just Typescript, but anyway it's good to have this solution for other developers.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for the answer and the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue. Telling webpack to stop following the symlink helped, here is the snippet in `vue.config.js`

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.resolve.symlinks(false);
},
```