# Vue.js 'import' does not work within external js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs2

Let me try to explain...

I have an `utils.js` file which does not work:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'; //https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs

exports.utils = (function() {
    someDateFunction() {
       ...some dayjs function calls ....
    }
})();
```

(As stated by an answering person thta it needs to be `module.exports` - well it does not matter. I have other source files where it works either way - with or without prenoted `module.`.)

When declaring the first line with the import statement vue-cli seems to properly compile. no error is shown. Running in the browser shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (utils.js?2f14:3)
    at Module../src/assets/js/utils.js (app.js:1541)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    ...
```

It do include/import this `utils.js`file by noting
`const { utils } = require("@/assets/js/utils.js");`

Why is it not allowed to import in the file?
If you need informations about versions I run let me know and also let me know what commands will show the demanded information (running on macos).

I already searched the web. the problem seems to be known in the past. There is some clues solving it with typescript or vue js.

Nothing works for me. I must not be the first one stumbling over issues like that, am I?
Any help appreciated.

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334703/845117

My dependencies in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.18.0",
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "cropperjs": "^1.5.9",
  "dayjs": "^1.9.6",
  "vue": "^2.6.12"
},
```

Comment: delete node_modules and install again

Comment: I can't reproduce this error in a default Vue CLI scaffolded project, using the code in question. Can you link to a GitHub repo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @tuhin47 your proposal did not work. I also fully set up the project with vue-cli.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I just found:

instead of

`import dayjs from 'dayjs';`

I use

`const dayjs = require('dayjs');`

That works. I figured it by by reading https://www.educba.com/require-vs-import/
I cannot really argue why it works the one and not the other way.
(Since I am not a native speaker I just understood 15% of the article. And I have not yet tried **tuhin47**'s proposal)

Answer (score 0):

It says exports does not exist because it should be module.exports = <your function definition>

Comment: This does not help my issue. Using the setup without import works faultlessly. Both statements would be accepted by vue-cli and the browser - with or without writing a leading 'module.'